# How to rebuild a widget whenever the validation function is triggered in TextFormField Flutter?

Tags: flutter, provider, textformfield

I'm receiving the following error message:

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for ErrorTextNotifier:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This _InheritedProviderScope<ValidityNotifier?> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because
the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be
built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is
allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant
will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
_InheritedProviderScope<ValidityNotifier?>
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
This is my code (I've had to omit a bunch of the code)
TextFormField

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ChangeNotifierProvider(
     create: (_) => ValidityNotifier(),
     child: Builder(builder: (context) {
       return Column(
         children: [
           TextFormField(
             autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
             validator: (str) {
               var validity = //custom validity function
               Provider.of<ValidityNotifier>(context, listen: false).setValidity(validity);
               return null;
             },
           ),
           Consumer<ValidityNotifier>(builder: (context, model, child) {
             if (model.isValid) {
               return Text("Custom Validity Message")
             }
             return const SizedBox.shrink();
           }),
         ],
       );
     }),
   );
 }
}

class ValidityNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
 bool _isValid = false;

 bool get isValid => _isValid;

 void setValidity(bool isValid) {
   _isValid=isValid;
   notifyListeners();
 }
}
```

I want the state to be changed every time the validation function is called, I've considered adding a listener to a TextEditingController but it would trigger a rebuild every time an input is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says you have concurrent builds running. When you call `setValidity` which triggers a rebuild due to `notifyListeners`, Flutter is already in the process of building the `TextFormField`.

You can use a [post frame callback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html), in this case the `setValidity` method call will run only once the current build is finished.

Instead of:

```
Provider.of<ValidityNotifier>(context, listen: false).setValidity(validity);
```

Try this:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  Provider.of<ValidityNotifier>(context, listen: false)
      .setValidity(validity);
});
```

Comment: Oh, but I want it to run every time a validation is performed...like say I want a special widget to be displayed under the textformfield.

Comment: Does it not run on every validation this way? I tried and it seemed to work.